# How to resize the window without hiding controls

Tags: c#, windows, forms

How can I resize a windows form without hiding controls that are positioned outside the form's new size?

Comment: Make sure that the window doesn't go smaller than a minimum that would occlude the buttons?

Comment: what are you trying to do? please provide some details.

Comment: Hi, Michael windows can go smaller than the minimum size but initially the buttons should not get hided while resizing the window ex) the button should almost to be docked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set the `anchor` property of your buttons or items in form.

If still you have issues, put the buttons or controls to `pannel` or `groupbox` and dock the buttons to parent container. Then apply anchor property for controller.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the .Anchor property of the buttons you want to avoid hiding. The anchor property can be set such that the placment of the buttons is alwas relative to one or more edges of the form. This way, when the form is resized, the buttons location is "anchored" to (for example) the Bottom and right edges of the form.

This will not prevent the user from making the form smaller than the minimum space required by the buttons, but I believe you can also set a minimum size property for the form.

Answer (score 0):

I Have found the similar issue and what i tried is to put all the buttons in a TableLayoutPanel and set the Anchor property of the buttons that way i am able to resize the button corresponding to the size of the form.
If any body has a better idea kindly suggest........